# Getting error for query in mongo 3.6.22 which works fine in 4.4.3 enterprise

Tags: mongodb

I'm getting an error for mongo query in mongo version 3.6.22 error as follows

> MongoError: arguments to $lookup must be strings, let: { profileIds:
> "$ProfileIDs" } is type object

But this same query works fine in mongo version 4.4.3 enterprise, and the ProfileIDs are String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.6 does not support `let` in `$lookup`. You need to write your query differently.